# Rails controller method that updates multiple tables values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, crud, nested-routes

I'm writing a #create method within a controller file that subsequently updates multiple different tables.

Once I create a reservation using `reservation#create` in Reservation Table, it should update three other tables:
1) `quantity_available` and `quantity_ordered` in Menus table
2) `meal_credits_left` on Account_Summaries table
3) `total_number_ordered` on Meals table

My `Api::ReservationsController` looks like this:

```
 def create
    @user = current_user
    user_summary = @user.account_summary

    @reservation = Reservation.new(
      user_id: params[:reservation][:user_id],
      menu_id: params[:reservation][:menu_id],
    )

    if @reservation.save
      menu = @reservation.menu
      meal = @reservation.meal

      user_summary.update_attributes(
        meal_credits_left: user_summary.meal_credits_left - 1
      )

      menu.update_attributes(
        quantity_available: menu.quantity_available -1,
        quantity_ordered: menu.quantity_ordered + 1
      )

      meal.update_attributes(
        total_number_ordered: meal.total_number_ordered + 1
      )

      render :show
    else
      render json: @reservation.errors.full_messages, status: 422
    end
  end
```

How do I set up the route to make sure that I can update those attributes in `ReservationsController#create`?

My routes look like this:

```
    resources :account_summaries, only: [:create, :update]
    resources :reservations, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
    resources :menus, only: [:index, :update]
    resources :meals, only: [:index, :update]
```

Comment: An observation: When making none-atomic updates like that, consider using a transaction of your db support it.

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking about routes configuration when your action already does what you say it should do. (btw, I'd use `meal.increment!(:total_number_ordered)` and `user_summary.decrement(:meal_credits_left)` to DRY it a little)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a route specified like below with API Version here it is v1

https://paweljw.github.io/2017/07/rails-5.1-api-app-part-3-api-versioning/

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do
       namespace :v1 do
          resources :reservations, only: [:create]
       end
  end
```

and call this method with METHOD: **POST**

```
http://api.localhost.com/v1/reservations/create
```

https://coderwall.com/p/t68tpa/setting-routes-for-rails-api